# how to print string which starts with $ in perl?

Tags: perl

i want to print string($abc$aaaaa#a$aa#) in file. how can i do that?
Below code is not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $temp = "$abc$aaaaa#a$aa#";
my $filename = '/log/a.log';
open(FH, '>', $filename) or die $!;
print FH $temp ;
close(FH);
```

Comment: "Its not working" is also a very bad way to describe your problem. Give details, errors, expected and actual output, not just "its not working".

Answer (score 5):

Double quotes interpolate variables. Use single quotes or backslash $ if you don't want that.

```
my $temp = '$abc$aaaaa#a$aa#';
# OR
my $temp = "\$abc\$aaaaa#a\$aa#";
```

You should always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. Perl would have told you what's wrong if you did.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $str = '$abc#def$xyz';
my $filename = 'result.txt';
open (FH, '>', $filename) or die $!;
print FH $str;
```

#Output

```
perl$ cat result.txt 
$abc#def$xyz
```